# WCF service working on debug but not working when calling from android

Tags: android, wcf, xamarin

I created a WCF service in Visual Studio 2012 that I intend to consume in Xamarin and have it save user registration information to a table in SQL server. The service works fine when debugging in Visual Studio, the data entries actually save to my table in SQL. I want to consume the service in Xamarin and here is my code:

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Data;
     using System.Data.SqlClient;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Runtime.Serialization;
     using System.ServiceModel;
     using System.ServiceModel.Web;
     using System.Text;
     using ItusService;


     using Android.App;
     using Android.Locations;
     using Android.OS;
     using Android.Util;
     using Android.Widget;

     //some code here...

     public static readonly EndpointAddress EndPoint = new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.1.155:12100/Service1.svc");

     private Service1Client service;

     protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
     {
         //some code here...
         InitializeService1Client();
     }
     private void InitializeService1Client()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding ();
        service = new Service1Client(binding, EndPoint);
    }
    async void AddressButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        //some code here...
        UserLocation useraddress = new UserLocation ();
        useraddress.ClientID = _client.Text = "ddsdfs";
        useraddress.FullName = _name.Text = "dsffdf";
        useraddress.LocationCoordinates = _locationText.Text;
        useraddress.LocationAddress = _addressText.Text;
        useraddress.DistressTime = _time.Text = "djdsk";
        string result = service.ToString ();
        _resultTxt.Text = result;
    }
```

I don't know if there is something I am missing out because nothing is being saved to my SQL table from my Android device. I debug using both an emulator and my device, nothing has been saved using both. I have opened the port for listening, I have created a reference file using silverlight slsvc tool according to the Xamarin Walkthrough http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/ I have tried everything I possibly can. Please help.

Comment: You are not sending anything to your service? The only thing I see is that you initialize the service, create a `UserLocation` locally and then you do a `service.ToString`? Which will probably output something like `[Service1Client]`. Don't you mean to do something like `service.MethodOnService(useraddress);`? Right now you are not calling any method on your WCF service.

Comment: The string values e.g `useraddress.FullName = _name.Text = "dsffdf";` are just test values. They will not be part of the final project.

Comment: Thanks @Gerald. In the tutorials I have gone though I haven't come across `service.MethodOnService(useraddress);` I will try it

Comment: Note; that was an **example**! `MethodOnService` isn't an actual method. It is a method on your own WCF service side that saves your data.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I see `service.MethodOnService();` needs to be defined in my WCF service code and does not exist in my `namespace`. I'm sure the WCF service is fine. I'm just missing something when I consume in Xamarin, I just can't see what. No tutorial is helping.

Comment: From what you are saying I am getting the feeling that you don't really understand what a (WCF) service is or does. Looking at the link you provided you see methods (at the WCF side) like `GetHelloData` and `SayHelloTo`. These are methods you can call on the service, from a client. From your client app, you import the service reference, this does nothing more than create a blueprint of what your service looks like on the outside. Then, with that refence, it knows what methods are available. In Visual Studio type `service.` and see what IntelliSense gives you, that is methods you can use.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I only get `GetLocationAsync` Method and `GetLocationCompleted` Event. The method I defined in my WCF is `GetLocation` I've been trying to progress using `service.GetLocationAsync (UserLocation useraddress)` and `useraddress` is not being recognised. Can you show me another example of how you would restructure the code.

Comment: You would have to show some code of the WCF side.

Comment: `public class UserLocation
    {
        string location_text = string.Empty;
        string address_text = string.Empty;
        string distresstime = string.Empty;
        string clientname = string.Empty;
        string clientID = string.Empty;

        [DataMember]
        public string LocationCoordinates
        {
            get { return location_text; }
            set { location_text = value; }
        }

       ` and it goes on like that for the other `string` variables

Comment: Sorry I cant make it more readable

Comment: @GeraldVersluis My `SqlCommand` works just fine so let me know if you need to see it aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general pattern for calling a WCF method is something like this (this is general WCF and really has nothing to do with Xamarin or Android)

```
// create the client and bind it
client = new ServiceClient(binding, endpoint);

// specify the callback
client.GetLocationCompleted += OnGetLocationCompleted;

// make the request to your method, passing any required parameters
client.GetLocationAsync(useraddress);
```

because the WCF call is async, you need to provide a callback method (the naming of the EventArgs class will depend on how your service is defined)

```
public void OnGetLocationCompleted(object sender, GetLocationCompletedEventArgs args) {

  // if something bad happend, args.Error will contain an exception
  // otherwise args.Result will contain any return value from you method

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jason. Let me try that now